# Create a scaffolding utility for java projects

Tags: java, automation, code-generation

I want to create a command line **scaffolding utility for a java based test automation project**, the way it happens with Rails or the play framework. I don't have much idea about how exactly rails or the play framework does that.
What I want to achieve is to basically:

- Generate a set of standard folders with some generic .java files and
  other framework utilities.
- Add reference to all the required JAR
  files in the project.
- Create configuration files

I think this could simply be done by writing a shell script. But before going for one, I would like to know if there's any other better way to create such a utility.  Any suggestions??

Comment: why no use Maven or gradle ?

Comment: never used maven or gradle. aren't they build tools?

Comment: yes, but looking at your requirement, by extending the Maven you can do the stuff you required.

Comment: One option could be you can write a java main method to generate the files using java.io.* or Fileutils and then trigger it using maven-exec-plugin.
We can independently trigger the maven-exec-plugin using mvn command